# New list each iteration for xml file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, list, elementtree

Sample XML file:

```xml
<main>
   <data>
      <some>111</some>
      <other>222</other>
      <more>333</more>
   </data>
   <data>
      <some>444</some>
      <other>555</other>
      <more>666</more>
   </data>
   <data>
      <some>777</some>
      <other>888</other>
      <more>999</more>
   </data>
</main>
```

I want to create a list for every subchild of data. For example:

```
1 = [111, 222, 333]
2 = [444, 555, 666]
3 = [777, 888, 999]
```

I want to create a loop that iterates through the whole XML file but then creates a new list (without overriding the previously created list) that stores the next set of data.

```
tree = et.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

num = 0
for child in root:
    num = []
    num += 1
    for element in child:
        num.append(element.text)
```

I know this code doesn't work but I hope it gives an idea of what I'm trying to get at. I am unsure how to approach this problem and am looking for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here (no external library is used)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<main>
   <data>
      <some>111</some>
      <other>222</other>
      <more>333</more>
   </data>
   <data>
      <some>444</some>
      <other>555</other>
      <more>666</more>
   </data>
   <data>
      <some>777</some>
      <other>888</other>
      <more>999</more>
   </data>
</main>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
collected_data = []
for d in root.findall('.//data'):
    collected_data.append([d.find(x).text for x in ['some', 'other', 'more']])
print(collected_data)
# if the output needs to be a dict
collected_data = {idx + 1: entry for idx, entry in enumerate(collected_data)}
print(collected_data)
```

output

```
[['111', '222', '333'], ['444', '555', '666'], ['777', '888', '999']]
{1: ['111', '222', '333'], 2: ['444', '555', '666'], 3: ['777', '888', '999']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to parse the `xml` and store the subchildren of each `data` block in a dictionary. `enumerate` can be used to provide the numerical parent key:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
d = soup(open('file.xml').read(), 'xml')
result = {i:[int(j.text) for j in a.find_all(re.compile('some|other|more'))] for i, a in enumerate(d.find_all('data'), 1)}
```

Output:

```
{1: [111, 222, 333], 2: [444, 555, 666], 3: [777, 888, 999]}
```

If you do not wish to create a dictionary, you can simply use unpacking:

```
a, b, c = [[int(i.text) for i in a.find_all(re.compile('some|other|more'))] for a in d.find_all('data')]
```

Output:

```
[111, 222, 333]
[444, 555, 666]
[777, 888, 999]
```